# C++ - working with char and how convert them to integer (extreme case number with a point)

Tags: c++

I have an array of characters and I want to take the characters in it (they are numbers) and get the same number only as an integer rather than as a character.

for example:

```
'1','2','3','5';

while(...){
num+= check - '0';
...
}
```

But in the end what i get is `11` , Because I connect them all. 
how i can get `int number = 1235`;

and if i have number with dot `12.123` what can i do?

thank you!

Comment: By using [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (for integers) or [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) (for floating point values)?

Comment: What you can do is spend some time studying what numbers mean. Given a number 23, what does the "2" mean? It means 20. 2*10. In a number 135, what does 1 mean? It means 100. Of course, you can't add 2 and 3 together and get 23, like your code is doing. Neither would adding 1, 3, and 5 result anywhere near 135. Now, spend a few minutes thinking about it, and the answer should be trivially obvious to you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to understand the difference between numeric addition and string concatenation.

Yes, in C++, the `+` operator is used for both of them (we call that operator overloading). But that doesn't mean it's the same thing.
In your example, you are subtracting ordinal number of character `'0'` from your `char` digit, which indeed gives you the numeric value your digit represents. You add these up, ending with 11.

If you want to concatenate the digits into a string, you need to 1/ create the string and 2/ concatenate the digits to it. As you'll be using the string's `+` operator, the compiler will do concatenation instead of numeric addition.

So something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    char a[] = {'1', '2', '3', '5'};

    int num = 0;
    std::string str;

    for (char c : a) {
        num += c - '0';
        str += c;
    }

    std::cout << "num == " << num << std::endl;
    std::cout << "str == " << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, and I forgot; should you want to get integer of 1235 (instead of string), just multiply current `num` value by 10 before each addition, likewise: `num = 10 * num + (c - '0')`.